# Android, typing Czech-specific characters on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: languages, localization, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I have a problem with some characters on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (GT-P5100). When I set language to "čeština" and type `ě` (Latin small letter E with caron) as result Android returns `ĕ` (Latin small letter E with breve) but when I use handwrite typing everything works fine. This behavior causes some search results to not be visible in my Android app. What can I do with it? I wouldn't like to prompt users to install another keyboards.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "handwrite typing". Is that an app? How are you typing in the characters in the first place? Is it possible that they keyboard is getting them wrong? Or the way they're displayed is not distinctive enough? (Honestly, at a quick glance, I can't tell the difference between the characters.) Is one valid for Czech and the other isn't? (That would mean that the developer for the keyboard got it wrong.)

Comment: I don't have access to device now but @Al-Everett look at this picture, please. I get first character by long press 'e' using standard samsung keyboard [link](http://www.gsmarena.com/showpic.php3?sImg=reviewsimg/samsung-galaxy-tab-2-101/review/shots/gsmarena_046.jpg&idReview=749&idPage=4) Second character I get by paint it on something like this: [link](http://www.gsmarena.com/showpic.php3?sImg=reviewsimg/samsung-galaxy-tab-2-101/review/shots/gsmarena_049.jpg&idReview=749&idPage=4). These two characters are very similar visually but have another unicode point Correct is char with caron.